# How to get related items from task?

Tags: list-item

I need to get filenames and their URL's from related items of list item (it is the Tasks list in PWA). How can i do that using REST API? The AttachmentFiles field is empty.

On the XHR tab of Chrome debugger i can see the ProcessQuery that returns data i need, but i can't understand how to request it. The preview looks like this:

[{*ObjectType*: "SP.RelatedItem", IconUrl: "icxls.png", ItemId: 1,…},…]
0:
{*ObjectType*: "SP.RelatedItem", IconUrl: "icxls.png", ItemId: 1,…}
IconUrl:"icxls.png"
ItemId:1
ListId:"5277b158-c82a-4170-9075-9463b9a8d94c"
Title:"download (1).xls"
Url:"/PWA/Teasty/Shared Documents/download (1).xls"
WebId:"549eacee-64cf-4614-b90a-12112e6d3feb"

I can get the data from the document library where the documents are stored but there is no link between documents and tasks.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.
First of all I switched on the RelatedItems field like shown here: https://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-column-related-items
Then I used ListId to get list items from the list and then filename and URL I've got from the EncodedAbsUrl and LinkFilename fields.